# Скрин всей страницы без Selenium на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, screenshots

коллеги! Как сделать скрин всей страницы без Selenium на python. Вот этот код делает скрин только видимой части экрана, а надо всей:

```
webbrowser.open_new('https://www.habr.com')
sleep(2)
pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

есть тулза которая может это сделать https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

я сайт сделал который делает pdf страницу https://note.knok.xyz/url2pdf/

исходник https://github.com/alexsok-bit/one_time_notes/blob/master/source/url2pdf/views.py#L38

Comment: спасибо. сейчас гляну